# Search DB using HTML form select and text input with php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a problem with my php project where I have to search my database using specific parameters given by the user.

This is my index.php where ALL content in printed out from database
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYgGb.jpg)

On my search page I have form from wich you have to choose product type ("keyboard, graphics card, motherboard....") and enter MAXIMUM PRICE for that product type, and then page returns content from database that meets the 
requirements parameters.

this is my code for now 
html part

```
<html>
<body>
    <form name="search" action="" method="post">
        <p>
            Odaberite proizvod: 
            <select id="proizvod"  selected="selected">
                <option value="tipkovnica">Tipkovnica</option>
                <option value="graficka">Graficka kartica</option>
                <option value="maticna">Maticna ploca</option>
                <option value="kuciste">Kuciste</option>
            </select>

        </p>
        <p>
            Cijena do: 
            <input type="text" name="cijena" value="">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="trazi" value="Trazi">
        </p>
    </form>
```

this is what I have for now
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YS1Wh.png)

and if I click on submit I get this error

> Notice: Undefined index: proizvod in D:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\RWA\contentSearch.php on line 25
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a non-object in D:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\RWA\contentSearch.php on line 32

and php part where I don't have a clue about how should I give that parameters to database...

```
        <?php
    if (isset($_POST["trazi"]))
    {
        $proizvod1 = $_POST['proizvod'];
        $cijenaDo = $_POST['cijena'];
        //getting all from database
            try 
            {
                $sql = 'SELECT id, proizvod, ime, cijena, slika FROM proizvodi WHERE proizvod LIKE '.$proizvod1.' ORDER BY ID ASC';
                $q = $conn->query($sql);
                $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            }
            catch (PDOException $pe)
            {
                die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
            }
    //PRINTING OUT THE TALBE WITH CONTENT
        ?>

        <table border="0"><tr>
            <?php 
            $i=0;
            $start = true;
            while ($r = $q->fetch()): 
                if($i %2 == 0 && !$start)
                {
                    echo '</tr><tr>';
                }
            ?>
                <td><a href="proizvod.php?id=<?php echo $r['id']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $r['slika']; ?>" width="300"></a></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="naziv"><h3><a href="proizvod.php?id=<?php echo $r['id']; ?>"><?php echo $r['ime']; ?></a></h3></div>
                    <div class="identifikator_modela">Proizvod: <?php echo $r['proizvod']; ?></div>
                    <div class="cijena">Cijena:<b> <?php echo $r['cijena'] . ' kn'; ?></b></div>
                </td>
            <?php $i++; $start = false; endwhile; ?>
        </tr></table>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
```

please help me and thank you in advance

Comment: Set name of <select> tag : `<select id="proizvod"  selected="selected" name="proizvod">`

Comment: I still get that fatal error :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Add `name` attribute for select tag 
   `<select name="proizvod" id="proizvod" selected="selected">`
2. Add single quote for `$proizvod1` (note: use a `'string'` after `LIKE`):
   `$sql = 'SELECT id, proizvod, ime, cijena, slika FROM proizvodi WHERE proizvod LIKE \''.$proizvod1.'\' ORDER BY ID ASC';`